# How to random assign 0 or 1 for x rows depend upon y column value in excel

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, statistics

I'm trying to generate a below sample data in excel. There are 3 columns and I want output similar present to **IsShade** column. I've tried =RANDARRAY(20,1,0,1,TRUE) but not working exactly.
I want to display random '1' value only upto value present in shading for NoOfcells value rows.

```
NoOfCells Shading IsShade(o/p)
5         2       0
5         2       0  
5         2       1
5         2       0
5         2       1
--------------------
4         3       1      
4         3       1  
4         3       0
4         3       1
--------------------
4         1       0
4         1       0
4         1       0
4         1       1
```

Appreciate if anyone can help me out.Python code will also work since the excel I will read in csv and try to generate output IsShade column. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

A small snippet of Python that writes your excel file. This code does not use `Pandas` or `NumPy`, only the standard library, to keep it simple if you want to use Python with Excel.

```
import random
import itertools
import csv

cols = ['NoOfCells', 'Shading', 'IsShade(o/p)']
data = [(5, 2), (4, 3), (4, 1)]  # (c, s)

lst = []
for c, s in data:          # c=5, s=2
    l = [0]*(c-s) + [1]*s  # 3x[0], 2x[1] -> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
    random.shuffle(l)      # shuffle -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
    lst.append(zip([c]*c, [s]*c, l))

# flat the list
lst = list(itertools.chain(*lst))

with open('shade.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(cols)
    writer.writerows(lst)
```

```
>>> lst
[(5, 2, 1),
 (5, 2, 0),
 (5, 2, 0),
 (5, 2, 0),
 (5, 2, 1),
 (4, 3, 1),
 (4, 3, 0),
 (4, 3, 1),
 (4, 3, 1),
 (4, 1, 0),
 (4, 1, 0),
 (4, 1, 1),
 (4, 1, 0)]
```

```
$ cat shade.csv
NoOfCells,Shading,IsShade(o/p)
5,2,0
5,2,0
5,2,1
5,2,0
5,2,1
4,3,1
4,3,1
4,3,1
4,3,0
4,1,0
4,1,1
4,1,0
4,1,0
```

Comment: Thank you @Corralien, how should I provide input like the above format since it in excel column

Comment: You need only `IsShade(o/p)` column?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number or rows for `RANDARRAY` to return using `COUNTA`.  Also. to exclude the dividing lines, test for `ISNUMBER`

```
=LET(Data,FILTER(B:B,(B:B<>"")*(ROW(B:B)>1)),IF(ISNUMBER(Data),RANDARRAY(COUNTA(Data),1,0,1,TRUE),""))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing but I'm unable to understand what will be B:B and other in the above formula. Should I use column name like B1 or D1 like that? Appreciate your response. thank you